# Can connect through ethernet shield but not when using MQTT on my arduino

Tags: amazon-web-services, arduino, client-server, mqtt, iot

I have been trying to send messages via MQTT from my Arduino to my amazon web server.  The following code connects the ethernet client but not the MQTT client.  Why would my MQTT client not be connecting?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

byte mac[]    = { 0x12, 0x42, 0x98, 0x85, 0x49, 0x3A }; //MAC address of server
char server[] = "http://52.1.29.117/"; //web address of server
IPAddress ip(172, 31, 51, 13); //IP address of server

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  // handle message arrived
}

EthernetClient ethClient;
PubSubClient client(server, 80, callback, ethClient);

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) {
        ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
    }

    // start the Ethernet connection:
    if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
        Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
        Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
    }
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("connecting...");

    if (ethClient.connect(server, 80)) {
        Serial.println("connected");
        // Make a HTTP request:
        ethClient.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.1");
        ethClient.println("Host: www.google.com");
        ethClient.println("Connection: close");
        ethClient.println();
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("connection failed");
    }

    //  if (client.connect(server)) {
    if (client.connect(server, "ubuntu", "")) {
        Serial.print("Data sent/n");
        client.publish("hello/world","hello world");
        client.subscribe("hiWorld");
    }
    else {
        Serial.print("nope");
    }
}

void loop()
{
  client.loop();
}
```

Comment: Can you connect to the broker on the Amazon machine from a different machine, e.g. with mosquitto_pub or mosquitto_sub?

Comment: @hardillb I cannot connect to the broker on the Amazon Web Server with anything.  It's automatically running mosquitto on port 1883 constantly and I realized now that my port was wrong but it still didn't fix anything.  I even tried to manually run mosquitto on another port and I couldn't connect to that either.  I set up a different server to mess around with and my Arduino was able to connect to that.  I think that it might have to do with firewall AWS' firewall settings

Answer (score 0):

IIRC AWS only opens a couple of specific ports, this may help you open up some more:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html